# How to customize a link function to perform a logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, link-function

My data was collected using [Randomized Response Technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_response). So I have additional variability into the data. I have a binary response variable. Should I customize a logit link function to incorporate the known probabilities of Randomized Response Technique to perform a logistic regression? I would like to know if this approach is appropriate or how one might correctly perform a regression with these kinds of responses.

If a customized link function is appropriate, I should customize the logit $\log \left({p \over 1-p}\right)$ to the customized $\log \left({p-0.25 \over 0.75-p}\right)$. Can anyone help me to do that? I don't have too much experience using R.

Comment: Although we could migrate this to SO where the `R` community likely could give you a good answer to the *programming* issue quickly, I would like to suggest instead that you edit your question to ask whether this approach is appropriate and how one might correctly perform a regression with these kinds of responses.

Comment: the only way I know is creating a custom set of functions to get a family through make.link, and then calling it from the glm. You need to define the function itself, the inverse, and the derivative I think.. Check make.link?, family? in help and at google

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do the necessary algebra. Others can add an example of how to do it in R. Suppose you response variable of interest is $Y$, which is the response to a question with answer "yes" or "no" (We code "yes" as 1 and "no" as 0).  Suppose we have a valid logistic regression model for $Y$:
$$
P(Y=\text{yes} | x) = g^{-1}(x) =\frac{e^{\beta' x}}{1+e^{\beta' x}}
$$
where $g$ is the link function, $g^{-1}$ the mean function.  We get 
$$
g(y) = \ln(\frac{y}{1-y})
$$
No, with the randomized resaponse technique, instead you observe a response variable $Y^*$
which is defined as $Y^* = \begin{cases} Y, ~~\text{with probability $1-q$} \\  
                                         \text{yes}, ~~\text{with probability $q$}.     \end{cases}$
Since now, in all cases, regardless of the values of the regressor variable(s) $x$, the probability of a "yes" response is at least $q$, so effectively we obtain the link function by restricting the probability parameter to range in $(q,1)$, not in $(0,1)$. Calculate:
$$
P(Y^*=\text{yes}|x)=q+(1-q)P(Y=\text{yes}|x)=\frac{q+e^{\beta'x}}{1+e^{\beta'x}}
$$
(where $q$ here is a known probability). Inverting this gives the link function
$g(y)=\ln(\frac{y-q}{1-y})$.

Comment: Using RRT, I have 0.25 probability of the answer
being a ‘forced yes’ and  0.5 probability of having to answer
the sensitive question truthfully. HOw I incorporate these probabilities in the link function?

Comment: Why do your two probabilities not sum to one? (0.25+0.5=0.75<1) Where did the missing 0.25 probability go?

Comment: Anyhow, did you understand the roloe of the parameter $q$ in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I already solve my problem!